# Loading options in Dropdown (using delegate)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, delegates, onclicklistener

Hello everyone

In my code, there is one drop down list. I want to add options to it. I have used following code. It is successfully adding those fields via jQuery. But after that, I can not select any option from that drop down. I think it is because of the Click event..

```
var myOptions = {
                        'India' : 'India',
                        'Sri Lanka' : 'Sri Lanka',
                        'UAE' : 'UAE',
                        'QATAR' : 'QATAR'
                    };
    var drop_down = jQuery("[name='ab-custom-field-1252']");
    jQuery("body").on('click',drop_down,function()
    {
        var mySelect = jQuery("[name='ab-custom-field-1252']");
        mySelect.html('');
        jQuery.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
        mySelect.append(
                jQuery('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
            );
            });
    });
```

Can anyone help me?
Your help will be highly appreciated.